# Who is the next boss after the golem and how do I find it?

Tags: terraria-console

What boss is the next boss to defeat after defeating the golem in the jungle temple in the underground jungle biome on the console version of Terraia? This question has been on my mind for some time now and I would like some advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Golem and Ocram are the two highest tier bosses in the console version. PC patches have extended the endgame, unfortunately, none of these have reached the console version.

http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Ocram

Answer (score 0):

First of all which console is one of the biggest questions for you. Second I know after golem is the lunar cultists on the PC. I believe on console it is ocram(the final boss).

Comment: I haven't seen the lunar cultists at the dungeon and I have defeated ocram ,is it because I kind of messed up the walling on the dungeon or is it because the lunar cultists are pc only?

Comment: Ocram is final boss so if you beat him you basically beat the game

Answer (score 0):

After the Golem, You should get about 10 adamantite, a Mechanical Skull, two Mechanical eyes, a bunch of souls of Light and Night, And that could be it. When you craft it at the Anvil(mythril of Adamantite anvil) you get the Suspicious looking Skull. Use it at around 7:30 PM IN GAME TIME. You will summon Ocram. He is the Final boss for Terraria Console. When he dies he has a chance of dropping some really good End game Armour. or materials to make them.

Answer (score 0):

Duke fishron is the new last boss. Summoned by finding a glow worm in an underground mushroom biome and then fishing at either sea with it!! Good luck finding the worm I've still get to even see one on 360 bout to go PC way better